# What is the current school of thought concerning precision of numeric conversions of measurements?

Tags: numerical-methods, soft-question

(EDIT: Changed title to say "precision" not "accuracy".)

(Now asked at https://matheducators.stackexchange.com/q/19373/8931)

I had a heated argument with someone online who claimed to be a school mathematics teacher of many years standing. The question which spurred this discussion was something along the lines of:

"A horseman was travelling from (location A) along a path through a forest to (location B) during the American War of Independence. The journey was of 22 miles. How far was it in kilometres?"

To my mind, the answer is trivially obtained by multiplying $22$ by $1.6$ to get $35.2$ km, which can be rounded appropriately to $35$ km.

I was roundly scolded by this ancient mathematics teacher for a) not using the official conversion factor of $1.60934$ km per mile and b) not reporting the correct value as $35.405598$ km.

Now I have serious difficulties with this analysis. My argument is: this is a man riding on horseback through a forest in a pre-industrial age. It would be impractical and impossible to measure such a distance to any greater precision than (at best) to the nearest $20$ metres or so, even in this day and age. Yet the answer demanded was accurate to the nearest millimetre.

But when I argued this, I was told that it was not my business to round the numbers. I was to perform the conversion task given the numbers I was quoted, and report the result for the person asking the question to decide how accurately the numbers are to be interpreted.

Is that the way of things in school? As a trained engineer, my attitude is that it is part of the purview of *anybody* studying mathematics to be able to estimate and report appropriate limits of accuracy, otherwise you get laughably ridiculous results like this one.

Comment: It's actually $1.60934\color{red}4$ km/mile, but there is a concept of [significant figures](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Significant_figures)

Comment: Isn't this a question for https://matheducators.stackexchange.com ?

Comment: @TorstenSchoeneberg The problem there is that I am not an educator, I just contribute to websites. I am too aware that I would teach things wrongly, and that would make the students think in incorrect ways, so I steer clear of formal teaching nowadays. Had too many run-ins with officialdom.

Comment: @J.W.Tanner My bad. Apologies, I should have caught that.

Comment: You don't have to be a math educator to ask a question on that site. I just think this is not a question about mathematics, but about math education, hence can be better *answered* by math educators than by mathematicians. (Of course there's an overlap.)

Comment: Ha, looking at the comments and answers over there, seems like my suggestion to ask at matheducators was fruitful. :-)

Comment: @TorstenSchoeneberg Surprisingly. I owe you!

Comment: Cross-posted: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3988907/14578, https://matheducators.stackexchange.com/q/19373/862.  Please [do not post the same question on multiple sites](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/64068).

Comment: This question has been asked-and-answered [elsewhere on the SE network](https://matheducators.stackexchange.com/questions/19373/).  Cross posting is strongly discouraged, and there is an expectation that cross-posted messages be modified to highlight the particular issues relevant to the different sites.

Answer (score 4):

"The current school of thought concerning accuracy of numeric conversions of measurements" is that the conversion is done with infinite precision. This allows to use the same formulas about falling stones independently of the used units.

Here we are in a high school environment with their special conventions. The standard rule is to use the given accuracy of the data, do exact numerical calculations with them, and perform a reasonable final rounding.

In the example of the horseman it is not expected that the pupil finds out the officially certified $60$ decimal places ISO factor between miles and kilometers. In his math book there is somewhere a line saying that $1$ mile $=1.609$ kilometers, or similar. The pupil is then expected to use this figure, compute with it, and make a final rounding to the precision of, e.g., meters, so that (s)he obtains $22\cdot1.609=35.398$ kilometers.

Answer (score 3):

Citing accuracy (precision is a better term) in calculations involving measurements can be a tricky thing. 22 miles is not the same as saying 22.0 or 22.00 etc... 22 miles has 2 sig figs whereas 22.0 has 3.

So 22 miles can be between 21.5 and 22.4 - even more tricky because 21.5 is not closer to 22 than 21 and what about 22.49? which has 4 sig digs. Most people have this assumption that when they state 22 miles they are meaning "exactly" 22 miles but in the case of measurement this can never be so. Better to say 22 miles +/- .5 but we all know  that's never going to happen. So the teacher admonishing you is incorrect because you are dealing with a measured quantity and using 1.6 which has 2 sig digs is fine by me (since 22 has 2 sig digs). 35 is better than 35.2 since 35 also has 2 sig digs whereas 35.2 has 3

There are a lot of complicated rules about how many sig digs your answer should have when multiplying (and you can look them up), based on the number of sig digs in the 2 numbers you are multiplying. This is further complicated here because the conversion factor is not a measured quantity.

The easiest rule of thumb (but not complete) is that your answer should have the same number of sig digs as the least significant measurement in the calculation. I know that this does not completely address the the problem of precision in an answer, but it is at least a start.

Another thought. The use of calculators further confuses the concept of precision when multiplying measured quantities as they give an answer which is "way" beyond the precision of the numbers being multiplied. In the dumbed-down curriculum of the 21st century the teaching of precision has pretty much been abandoned in high school as it has been classified as too difficult to learn and not worth the effort.

Comment: We were taught the difference between accuracy and precision in A-level physics, and also taught how to calculate the precision of derived quantities based on the various combination laws of errors. It was covered in (part of) a single teaching session and we were subsequently expected to use what we had been taught in the course of our work. But that was over 40 years ago and I understand that the world has taken great strides forward since then.

Comment: I agree, precision is the way to go. Sig digs was kind of like a half-way attempt in high school to try and get a some kind of handle on the precision of an answer without the complications of doing it correctly.

Comment: Incidentally, I have changed "accuracy" to "precision" in the title. Good call, my mistake.